# Siemens NX 10 installation: Could not determine filesystem containing /usr/ugs100

Tags: filesystems, ksh, disk-usage

I debug script to install Siemens NX 10 applications for Debian 8.2, and get the warning:

> Could not determine filesystem containing /usr/ugs100
>   space calculations may be incorrect.

The source code of the script: [ug_install](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5ldtvjpsx2wjp9/ug_install?dl=0) (too large to post here). The code fragment generating this message, together with the two functions that it calls and other relevant functions:

```
Init_fs_arrays() # Initializes the File System array.
{       # RKB Thu Jan 31 22:39:57 PST 1991
        # RKB Updated: Sep 28 15:26:28 PDT 1992
        # RKB updtd: Jul  6 22:51 93 V10.1.1 make generic.
        # RKB updtd: Mar  7 18:34 94 V103P2E streamline, rm "set --".
        # RKB updtd: Mar  9 22:34 94 V103P2E rm test -s for FS_FILE, just wait f
        # RKB updtd: Wed Apr 20 2005 NX4P11 Added Linux support.
        # This function initializes the FS_NAME & FS_FREE 
        # arrays based on the contents of $FS_FILE
        FS_FILE="$UGS_TMP/filesystem_info" # File name to read the results from.
        $VECHO "${MSG}Initializing File System array ..."
        wait $SIZE_FS_PID # in case the file is not ready, wait for the bg job.
        I=0 # Initialize the index
        # Linux
        # cat $FS_FILE | while read NAME SPACE  ; do
        # Linux cant do "cat file | while read" "must use while read done < file
        while read NAME SPACE ; do
                FS_NAME[$I]=$NAME ; FS_FREE[$I]=${SPACE:=0} ; FS_NEEDED[$I]=0
                ((I+=1))  # Increment the index.
        done < $FS_FILE
        return 0
} # End of Init_fs_arrays

Get_fsindex() # Get the index number to supplied file system name. 
{       # RKB Mon Jan 21 21:00 91
        # RKB Mar  8 23:59 94 V103P2E chg to use while loop not grep -n. faster.
        : ${FS_NAME[*]:?} # Required variable internal check.
        : ${1:?} # Required arg internal check.
        I=0 # Init the index counter
        # Loop thru the FS_NAME array to get index number for filesystem in arg 
        while [ $I -le ${#FS_NAME[*]} ] ; do
                [ $1 = "${FS_NAME[$I]}" ] && { echo $I ; return 0; }
                ((I+=1)) # Increment the index.
        done 
        unset FS_INDEX ; 
        return 1 # Didn't find the file system.
} # End of Get_fsindex

Get_fs_info() # Returns filesystem info for the directory argument.
{   
    # Requires 2 global variables.
    : ${DF_CMD:?cmd var must be set to use this function. }
    : ${AWK_CMD:?cmd var must be set to use this function. }
    # Requires 2 args; a switch and a target directory.
    TARGET=$2 ; : ${TARGET:?} # Internal check
    #
    # If dir doesn't exist, check parent.
    while [ ! -d $TARGET ] ; do
        [ -f $TARGET ] && { # error if a file exists.
            print "${ERR}directory name expected. file exists: $TARGET" >&2
            return 1 ;
        }
        TARGET=`dirname $TARGET`
    done 
    #
    # Do appropriate action based on the switch. The options are:
    # use -sp to get free space, -fs for real filesystem name, -mnt returns
    # the mount point and -nfs returns true if the filesystem is NFS mounted, 
    # and false if it's not.
    #
    # Set machine specific number for the df field containing filesystem.
    [ $MACHINE = IRIX -o $MACHINE = IRIX64 ] && N=6 || N=5
    case $1 in 
        -fs*)  $DF_CMD $TARGET | tr "\012" " " | $AWK_CMD '{print $(NF-$N)}' ;;
        -mnt*) $DF_CMD $TARGET | tr "\012" " " | $AWK_CMD '{print $NF}'      ;;
        -nfs)  $DF_CMD $TARGET | tr "\012" " " | $AWK_CMD '{print $(NF-$N)}' | grep ":/" >$NULL || return 1 ;;
        -sp*)  $DF_CMD $TARGET | tail -1 | $AWK_CMD '{printf("%d",$(NF-2))}' ;;
    esac
    return 0
} # Get_fs_info

…
    SPACE_REQUIRED_KB=0 
    # Get the mount point for BASE_DIR.
    BASE_MNT_PT=`Get_fs_info -mnt $BASE_DIR` || {
            print "${WARN}Could not determine mount point for $BASE_DIR
                              \r\tFile System information may be incorrect. 
    } # Shouldn't be any problem, but just to be safe.
    FS_INDEX=`Get_fsindex $BASE_MNT_PT` || {
            print "${WARN}Could not determine filesystem containing $BASE_DI
                              \r\tspace calculations may be incorrect. "
    } # Shouldn't be any problem, but just to be safe.
    #
```

The contents of the temporary file `/tmp/filesystem_info`:

```
/dev    10240
/run    1621732
/dev/shm    4031816
/run/lock   5116
/dev/mqueue 0
/dev/hugepages  0
/boot/efi   72815
/run/user/116   815520
/run/user/1000  815484
```

1. That the `Get_fs_info` function returns?
2. How to understand the contents of the `filesystem_info` file?

Comment: your script snippet doesn't give much information, but looking at the error message and the contents of the `/tmp/filesystem_info` file, I am guessing (just a guess, not a certainty) it is looking for the /usr directory to be mounted as a filesystem and not seeing it to be so. You need to ask this question to the vendor  (Siemens ??) as it is extremely application specific. Chances of finding someone here, having had the same problem is nearly zero. My 2 cents

Comment: I see that the installation creates a directory `/usr/ugs100` for application and service directory `/usr/ugs100.[number]`.

Comment: Again, this is an educated guess, so take it with a grain of salt. Well authored installer scripts/programs, want to install their binaries to a place, which will not jeopardize system operation. Since yours wants to install under /usr and /usr not being a separate filesystem, if this app somehow starts writing to this installation directory, say some excessive logs, it will fill up your root filesystem and your system will stop running at some point due to not finding available disk space to store system related information. Again, please contact the vendor and listen to what they will say.